# Get CLSID key issue

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get `CLSID` for `Control Panel` and `Add or Remove Programs` on `Windows XP`.

**Example:**
`shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}` - only works from Vista (Control Panel).

Any suggestions how to get it?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the CLSID?

Comment: @zett42 

I want to get installed apps information on `Win XP` using `Shell` by `SHParseDisplayName` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get CLSID for Control Panel

You can use `shell:ControlPanelFolder` instead of CLSID which is [supported on Win XP](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/).

You may also get the folder location via [`SHGetSpecialFolderLocation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762203(v=vs.85).aspx) by passing [`CSIDL_CONTROLS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx) for parameter `nFolder`.

> and Add or Remove Programs

Raymond Chen has a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131230-00/?p=2233), where he [comments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131230-00/?p=2233#comment-1097093):

> Windows NT/2000/XP doesn't have a "Programs and Features" folder, so
>   the question is moot. If you mean "enumerate all installed
>   applications", there's no built-in way of doing this. You have to
>   mimic what "Add/Remove Programs" does, which is messy because
>   Add/Remove Programs enumerates apps from some places that may not be
>   obvious (like the MSI store).

Comment: I will check it and reply later. Thanks.

Comment: I think the only way to get apps info are to check the `Uninstall` keys in the registry?

Comment: Yes, but as Raymond writes, _Add/Remove Programs enumerates apps from some places that may not be obvious_. I don't know what these places are though.

Comment: You could also run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see which other registry keys besides `Uninstall` are queried by Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: `Process Monitor` is only supported by `Win Vista` and higher. I already have it implemented on Vista and later except for `Uninstall` path.

I use to get identifier for example for `Install path` this code:
`CComVariant installLocation;
hr = psf2->MapColumnToSCID(10, &pscid);
hr = psf2->GetDetailsEx(pidlChild, &pscid, &installLocation);`

But there are no identifier to get `Uninstall path` for the apps.
Also my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811680/apps-information-from-shell-issue

Comment: @Cobra91151 You propably have to read this from `Uninstall` key in registry.

Comment: Yes. I think there is no built-in way to get the application `Uninstall path`.

Comment: @Cobra91151: "*Process Monitor is only supported by Win Vista and higher*" - older versions (before the Microsoft takeover) work on Win2K and XP. See [Where to get working Sysinternals tools for Windows 2000?](https://serverfault.com/questions/129044/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau

I will check it. Thanks.